# Play Framework 2.5 with Couchbase 4.5

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, couchbase

I am currently playing around with Play Framework and as database I wanna use Couchbase 4.5 (which is in beta right now, but shouldn't be a problem).

Here's my question:
In the Couchbase documentation they suggest using only one instance of *CoucbaseCluster* and just one instance of *Bucket*.
But how do I establish these instances at startup and use them globally in all my controllers.
I am already so far to know that I have to use Dependency Injection but I don't have a clue how to realize this.

Wait now by writing this I realize that some kind of global Object with those instances is old school. I have to inject those instances into all my controllers that should use them, right?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes you're on the right track with DI. You would create a module, bind it as a singleton, and do so eagerly I assume. Play has Guice support built in, and it's pretty easy to do this using it. Check the docs for some pointers: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection For an example look at ReactiveMongo which uses this pattern.

Comment: @MichaelKendra Hey thanks for the direction. I read that page again with more concentration and together with the examples in play I got it running!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some tinkering I got it working:

I created a Singleton class with my buckets

```
@Singleton
class CouchbaseConnectionPool @Inject() (appLifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle){
  val cluster=CouchbaseCluster.create("127.0.0.1")
  val dataBucket=cluster.openBucket("data")
  val fileBucket=cluster.openBucket("files")
  appLifecycle.addStopHook { () =>
    cluster.disconnect()
    Future.successful(())
  }
}
```

and the controller looks like this

```
class DirectDBAccess @Inject() (pool:CouchbaseConnectionPool) extends Controller {
  def listAll(dbtype:String) = Action {
    val result:N1qlQueryResult  = pool.dataBucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple("select bucket.* from bucket where type=\""+dbtype+"\""))
    val data=result.allRows().mkString(",")
    val total=result.allRows().length
    val response="{data:["+data+"],total:"+total+"}"

    Ok(response).as("application/json")
  }
}
```

and to finally bind it all together I added

```
bind(classOf[CouchbaseConnectionPool]).asEagerSingleton()
```

to module.scala and it works!